# AngularJS ng-repeat shows undefined for prototype function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm running into an issue where a function is returning undefined in a select.

```
<select name="supervisor"
    ng-model="editJudge.superID"
    ng-options="supervisor.legalProID as supervisor.fullName for supervisor in supervisors"
    class="form-control">
```

Here's my function to load supervisors.

```
function getLegalProfessionalsBroken() {
LegalProfessionalResource.query({isValid: true}).$promise.then(function(legalProfessionals) {
    $scope.supervisors = _.map(legalProfessionals, function(legalProfessional) {
        return new LegalProfessional(legalProfessional);
    });
});
```

}

And here's my LegalProfessional class.

```
function LegalProfessional(obj) {
var properties = $.extend({
    legalProID: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    middleName: null,
    email: null,
    isActive: true,
    insertedDate: null,
    insertedBy: null,
    modifiedDate: null,
    modifiedBy: null,
    deletedDate: null,
    deletedBy: null,
    typeID: null,
    superID: null
}, obj);

this.legalProID = properties.legalProID;
this.firstName = properties.firstName;
this.lastName = properties.lastName;
this.middleName = properties.middleName;
this.email = properties.email;
this.isActive = properties.isActive;
this.insertedDate = properties.insertedDate;
this.insertedBy = properties.insertedBy;
this.modifiedDate = properties.modifiedDate;
this.modifiedBy = properties.modifiedBy;
this.deletedDate = properties.deletedDate;
this.deletedBy = properties.deletedBy;
this.typeID = properties.typeID;
this.superID = properties.superID;
```

}

```
LegalProfessional.prototype = {
fullName: function() {
    return this.lastName + ', ' + this.firstName;
}
```

};

When I run it like this I'm getting 'undefined, undefined' for all of the options.  If I put a breakpoint in it looks like 'this' is scoped to the html  element rather than LegalProfessional.

I can comment out the fullName function from my LegalProfessional class and then change my getLegalProfessionals class to add fullName and things work as expected.

```
function getLegalProfessionals() {
LegalProfessionalResource.query({isValid: true}).$promise.then(function(legalProfessionals) {
    $scope.supervisors = _.map(legalProfessionals, function(legalProfessional) {
        return new LegalProfessional(legalProfessional);
    });
    $scope.supervisors.forEach(function(supervisor) {
        supervisor.fullName = function() {
            return supervisor.lastName + ', ' + supervisor.firstName;
        };
    });
});
```

}

Both ways I can put a breakpoint in the controller and $scope.supervisors[0].fullName() gives me the value I expect to see.

I would much rather go with the 1st option so I only have one place to maintain it as I use this in several places within my application.

I'm sure it's a scope issue with ng-repeat but I'm not sure how to combat it.

Comment: did you forget to call the function? `ng-options="supervisor.legalProID as supervisor.fullName() for supervisor...`

Comment: It is working as expected, Please have a look at: http://plnkr.co/edit/FWD4wrG1cVbzjI7cQyEL?p=preview

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing!  If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue with `ng-options`.

It is working as expected.

Please have a look at: http://plnkr.co/edit/FWD4wrG1cVbzjI7cQyEL?p=preview

Comment: It's a matter of fullName v. fullName().  Got tripped up not having to add the parenthesis when adding the function from the controller.